Indicator function necessary for independence from filtration?
I have a question to the solution of a problem I am working on. I will first give you the Task and the Solution and then ask my question.
Task:
Let $Z_0 = 1$ and
$$
Z_{n+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{Z_n} X_{n+1,i}.
$$
Here, $(X_{n,i})_{n, i \geq 1}$ are independent and identically distributed random variables taking values in $\mathbb{N}_0$, with $\mathbb{E}[X_{n,i}] = \mu > 1$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X_{n,i}) = \sigma^2 < \infty$ for all $n, i \geq 1$.
Furthermore, let $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(X_{k,i}, i \geq 1, 1 \leq k \leq n)$ and $M_n = \frac{Z_n}{\mu^n}$ for $n \geq 0$. Then $(M_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is a martingale with respect to the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n \geq 0}$.
Show that:
(a) For all $n \geq 1$, it holds almost surely that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[(Z_n - \mu Z_{n-1})^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}\right] = Z_{n-1} \sigma^2.
$$
Solution
We calculate
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[(Z_n - \mu Z_{n-1})^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[Z_n^2 - 2\mu Z_n Z_{n-1} + \mu^2 Z_{n-1}^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}\right]
$$
$$
= \mathbb{E}[Z_n^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}] - 2\mu Z_{n-1} \mathbb{E}[Z_n \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}] + \mu^2 Z_{n-1}^2.
$$
Now, we determine $\mathbb{E}[Z_n^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]$. It holds almost surely that
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z_n^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{Z_{n-1}=k\}} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{Z_{n-1}} X_{n,i}\right)^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}\right]
$$
$$
\overset{\text{mon. conv.}}{=} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{1}_{\{Z_{n-1}=k\}} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} X_{n,i}\right)^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}\right]
$$
$$
\overset{\text{meas.}}{=} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{Z_{n-1}=k\}} \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} X_{n,i}\right)^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}\right]
$$
$$
\overset{\text{indep.}}{=} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{Z_{n-1}=k\}} \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} X_{n,i}\right)^2\right].
$$
and so on.
Question
Is the indicator function $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{Z_{n-1}=k\}}$ to create independence of $X_{n,i}$ from $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$? Or could we neglect the filtration without the indicator function? If yes, I do not see any reason to use the indicator function.

You are correct. You can't neglect the filtration without the indicator function because the upper bound of $\sum_{i=1}^{Z_{n-1}}$ is not independent of the filtration. Summing over the possible values of $Z_{n-1}$ with an indicator function is a particularly nice and rigourous way to extract this dependence and make the calculation tractable.
